# Android activity Lifecycle does not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-activity, surfaceview, activity-lifecycle

I'm developing a android 2D game in android studio.

I have a problem with my activity Lifecycle.

My question is this:

I have 2 activities. One named LauncherActivity, and the other named MainActivity.

When I first launch the app, the LauncherActivity launches, and everything works just fine.Then, when I go the the MainAcitivty, which is the activity that hold my game, meaning that it has the line : setContentView(new GameController(this)), everything still works fine. Then when I go back to the launcher activity, everything still works fine, but NOW when I'm trying to go back to the game, the MainActivity, in the second time, then the Lifecycle is as follow:

onCreate(),onStart(),onResume(),onPause(),onStop(),onResume().

This is ruining all my game, because I have specific things in my onStop() method, which I can not allow them to be executed when the activity launch.

Does someone know how to fix this ? What am I doing wrong ?

If I was not clear, please ask me and I will explain.

Comment: Do you call `finish()` or `startActivity()`at your second activity to move back to the first one?

Comment: startActivity()

Comment: When you call startActivity you "kill" the previous one. I think if you use `onBackPressed()` the activity will be kept in the stack and the final method that will be called is the `onStop()`. As a workaround you could save in your app's sharedpreferences the things you want to keep and get them when you get back to the second activity.

Comment: I did not understand. What you are saying is that if I use startActivity() this does not supposed to happen ?

Comment: And I'm not using onBackPressed() method

Comment: Thats what I'm saying. If you use onBackPressed() method your problem will be solved.

Comment: How can I solve this without removing startActivity ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154184/discussion-between-antonis-st-and-levi-omer).

Answer (score 0):

Android call onStop when *the activity is no longer visible*. Please review document. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I know. But it does not happen

Comment: What is happen, is that onPause() called, the activity then no longer visible, and only after 10 seconds or more the onStop() is called

Comment: Please share your log or video, maybe i can help you.

Comment: Can u invite me to private chat ?

Comment: When I move from activity 1 to activity 2, this is the log:



 E/Activity1: onResume()



 E/Activity2: onStart()
 E/Activity2: onResume()
 E/Activity2: onPause()
 E/Activity2: onAttachedToWindow
 E/Activity2: onStart()
 E/Activity2: onResume()
 E/Activity2: onAttachedToWindow
 E/Activity2: onWindowFocusChanged
 E/Activity2: onStop
 E/Activity1: onStop was called

Comment: I think your android app has memory leaks. You should review code.